# Inheritance object simplexml with android

Tags: java, android, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization, simple-framework

I'm trying to use simplexml to deserialize an object and code that works using java doesn't work over Android.

The simple class:

```
@Root    
public class GenericContainer
{
  @Element
  public MainEntity el;
}
```

That is declared:

```
GenericContainer genContainer = new GenericContainer();
genContainer.el = new SubClassBEntity(); //SubClassBEntity is a Subclass of MainEntity
```

Is serialized and generates a xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<genericContainer>
  <el class="test.entities.SubClassBEntity>
    <x>1</x>
  </el>
</genericContainer>
```

If I try to deserialize the xml using java all goes ok but if I do the same using android I get a crash where exception message is `test.entities.SubClassBEntity`.

Any idea to fix this problem? 
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps there is a difference, in the bookstore SimpleXML, between Java and Andorid's implementation of.

I had a similar problem with another library XML. There were differences between Java SE and Android.

Comment: Yes I know, android produces this kind of headaches...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that I found is use `@ElementUnion` put all the possibilities inside. It's a dirty solution because you can have a base class with 50 subclasses and you will have to put all. Automatic refactoring will don't change the annotations and it will be a piece of error prone code.